# JS spinner only shows after action completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spinner

This is a pretty consistent issue we've been struggling with for quite some time.

The page uses the [fgnass](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) spinner. The page is built on angular. When performing any kind of lengthy dom manipulation, I try and call the spinner, then perform said dom manipulation (for instance, calling pagination or search on rather large data sets). The actions can take a few seconds, thus the reason for the spinner: so the user knows stuff is happening, and to wait.

What I try to do is.

```
function callSpinner()
{
    j$("div[class^='ui-dialog']").addClass('dialog_spinner');
    j$("div[class^='ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content']").css("display", "none");
    j$('#progressSpinner').dialog('open');
}
function closeSpinner()
{
    j$('#progressSpinner').dialog('close');
    j$("div[class^='ui-dialog']").removeClass('dialog_spinner');
}
```

This is using the angular pagination lib by Michael Bromley found [here.](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) This is happening inside the scope.setCurrent function of his library.

```
scope.setCurrent = function(num) {
callSpinner();
paginationService.setCurrentPage(paginationId, num);
closeSpinner();
}
```

That said, it occurs with a standard Angular filter as well.

This is the createSpinner method called on page creation (and I also launch the spinner once on page load)

```
function CreateSpinner()
{
    // initialize spinner.
var opts = {
    lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
    length: 15, // The length of each line
    width: 5, // The line thickness
    radius: 15, // The radius of the inner circle
    corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
    rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
    direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
    color: '#E68A2E', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
    speed: 1, // Rounds per second
    trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
    shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
    hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
    className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
    zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
    top: '50', // Top position relative to parent in px
    left: '30' // Left position relative to parent in px
};
var target = document.getElementById('progressSpinner');
$spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
j$("div[class='ui-widget-overlay ui-front']").addClass('overlay_style1');
}
```

And here's the HTML for the spinner tag I'm targeting.

```
<div id="progressSpinner" title="Progress" style="display: none; background-color: #000000; z-index: 1200; opacity: 0.8; padding: 0;"></div>
```

What actually happens though, is it fires off the pagination action, and waits to call the spinner until after the pagination process has finished. So the page just does nothing, the pagination finishes and the form is updated, then the spinner launches, then it closes.

As I said, I create the spinner on page load, then call the callSpinner function while the page is prepared. That works fine.

I can call callSpinner at any time, and it works fine as well.

I can even open the spinner in the console, then trigger the pagination click, and the spinner keeps spinning.

Comment: where's the real code? We can't guess what your functions do or how spinner is integrated

Comment: Please could you provide a link of some kind to your actuall code? (website or JSfiddle). Your pseudocode seems to represents no issue.

Comment: Added a lot of real code. Should be enough (I hope). Not sure how to set a JSFiddle up with the sheer scope of data size I'd need, and I can't share the actual website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After various attempts at doing different things, I've finally got it working. There was never, at any point, anything specifically wrong with my code. If I put debug breaks at each code line for

```
callSpinner();
paginationService.setCurrentPage(paginationId, num);
closeSpinner();
```

everything works how it should.

I finally worked out that what's happening is the browser takes all 3 lines of code at once. And it decides it's more important to run the setCurrentPage function above everything else. So it paginates the entire thing, then it'll run callSpinner(); Then it immediately runs close spinner.

My solution:

```
callSpinner();
setTimeout(function () {
    scope.$evalAsync(
        function( scope ) {
            paginationService.setCurrentPage(paginationId, num);
            closeSpinner();
        }
    );
}. 200);
```

Reasoning: As near as I can tell, by putting the pagination call into a timeout with a short delay, it makes sure the callSpinner(); executes before doing anything else.

Originally, I just had the timeout, but as soon as the code in the timeout was called, it would trigger the closeSpinner(); line first, then do the pagination call. So I used Angular's $evalAsync on it, and that got it going right.